# I am trying to plot a k means cluster plot in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am trying to plot a k means cluster for the following data set:

```
Elo Rank    Elo Score
Man City    1208
Man United  1123
Tottenham   1121
Liverpool   1107
Chelsea 1064
Arsenal 1032
Crystal Palace  996
Burnley 992
Everton 988
Bournemouth 978
West Ham    976
Newcastle   970
Leicester   965
Brighton    955
Southampton 938
Watford 927
Huddersfield    926
West Brom   919
Stoke   914
Swansea 901
```

I am trying to run kmeans code but Im getting the error:

```
'Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE): 'x' must be numeric'
```

Im assuming this is because of the first column. however I want to label each point on the plot with the team name so I know which point is what.
an example of what I want is the first diagram in this link:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/clustering-in-r-programming/

how do i go about plotting this?

Comment: What is the R code you are actually running?

Comment: You only have a single metric (that is, a single data dimension). The example you are trying to replicate has an x and a y variable.

Comment: set.seed(123)
res.km <- kmeans(scale(dfcluss), 4, nstart = 25)
res.km$cluster        is the code I am running with dfcluss being the data. Is there anyway I can still plot a cluster with this dataset?

Comment: My aim is to split the teams into 4 clusters just so I can compare them separately, and I want to show the clusters in a visualization. Could I maybe add another column with the rank number (ie 1,2,3,....20)? would this help provide another metric?

Comment: please provide a reproducible example:: so we can copy paste your code and reproduce the mistake you see

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want something like this. I created 4 clusters of your data using `kmeans`. You can use this code:

First your data:

```
# A tibble: 20 × 2
   `Elo Rank`     `Elo Score`
   <chr>                <dbl>
 1 Man City              1208
 2 Man United            1123
 3 Tottenham             1121
 4 Liverpool             1107
 5 Chelsea               1064
 6 Arsenal               1032
 7 Crystal Palace         996
 8 Burnley                992
 9 Everton                988
10 Bournemouth            978
11 West Ham               976
12 Newcastle              970
13 Leicester              965
14 Brighton               955
15 Southampton            938
16 Watford                927
17 Huddersfield           926
18 West Brom              919
19 Stoke                  914
20 Swansea                901
```

Next scale your data (really important for kmeans clustering):

```
df$`Elo Score` <- scale(df$`Elo Score`)
```

Next create 4 clusters:

```
library(factoextra)
# Compute k-means with k = 4
km.res <- kmeans(df$`Elo Score`[!is.na(df$`Elo Score`)], 4)
```

Results:

```
print(km.res)

K-means clustering with 4 clusters of sizes 9, 1, 4, 6

Cluster means:
        [,1]
1 -0.1962215
2  2.4819362
3  1.2379850
4 -0.9446472

Clustering vector:
 [1] 2 3 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 4 4 4 4 4 4

Within cluster sum of squares by cluster:
[1] 0.5729761 0.0000000 0.3216049 0.1143089
 (between_SS / total_SS =  94.7 %)

Available components:

[1] "cluster"      "centers"      "totss"        "withinss"     "tot.withinss" "betweenss"    "size"         "iter"        
[9] "ifault"
```

Finally add your clusters to data:

```
# add clusters to data
df$cluster <- km.res$cluster
```

Result:

```
 # A tibble: 20 × 3
   `Elo Rank`     `Elo Score`[,1] cluster
   <chr>                    <dbl>   <int>
 1 Man City                2.48         2
 2 Man United              1.47         3
 3 Tottenham               1.44         3
 4 Liverpool               1.28         3
 5 Chelsea                 0.764        3
 6 Arsenal                 0.382        1
 7 Crystal Palace         -0.0477       1
 8 Burnley                -0.0955       1
 9 Everton                -0.143        1
10 Bournemouth            -0.263        1
11 West Ham               -0.286        1
12 Newcastle              -0.358        1
13 Leicester              -0.418        1
14 Brighton               -0.537        1
15 Southampton            -0.740        4
16 Watford                -0.871        4
17 Huddersfield           -0.883        4
18 West Brom              -0.967        4
19 Stoke                  -1.03         4
20 Swansea                -1.18         4
```